# Ubuntu Server : Running a Spring Boot Docker image with NGINX?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, nginx

I am really stuck with NGINX and Docker.

I have created a Docker image of my Spring Boot project like that "docker run -d -p 8090:80 backend".

In Docker Log everything is ok, the App is running like a charm, but...

In my NGINX config I try to implement that image, and I configure a conf file backend.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

I have aslo open the port with uwf, for NGINX and my 8090 port.

When I tried to go on http://mydomain or even http://example.com:8090, or http://localhost:8090 I got a **502 Bad Gateway**. Even with a curl http://localhost.

In the logs of NGINX I have found that : **connect() failed (111: Unknown error)** or **nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8090 failed (98: Unknown error)**.

Honestly I am totally lost, so if you know how to help I would really appreciate :)

Comment: `localhost` means the container itself, so you can't use that in `proxy_pass`. If you connect both containers to the same docker network, you can use the container name of the Spring Boot container as the host name.

Comment: Your docker port config should just be `-p 8080:8080`.  Nginx will want to take port 80.  I don't know where you got the port 8888 in your error as you don't show that anywhere.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. I tried to change the proxy_pass with the name of my container but I have an error when I restart NGINX.

So I decided to create a network like this :

docker network create my-network
docker run --name backtmc --network my-network -d -p 8090:8090 backtmc
docker run --name nginx --network my-network -v /path/to/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/backend.conf:ro -p 8081:80 -d nginx

And I have change my nginx conf file.

But the image is up few minutes and stop, and the URL is not working.

Comment: Ok, finally I change my strategy, I built my docker image like that :

sudo docker run --net=host -d -p 8090:80 -t backtmc

It works but... I get a warning : WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode.

Is it bad ?